# How to delay function execution when it calls 2 and more times in JS?

Tags: javascript

Below is the link with my code. Please click the button several times in order  to see what I mean exactly. I am trying to call the same function more than once with  intervals between function calls. Please help me.
  http://codepen.io/arminemash/pen/KzBBjN

**HTML**

```
<div id='generalwrapper'> 
    <div id='general'>                  
        <div  id='1' class='cell' onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>
        <div  id='2' class='cell' onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>           
        <div  id='3' class='cell'  onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>
        <div   id='4' class='cell'   onclick='simon(this.id)'></div>
     </div> 
    <div id='buttondiv'>
        <button onclick='startGame()'>On</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var browser=[];
var count = 1;

function startGame(){ 
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++){       
        browserturn();  
    }
    count++;
}

function browserturn(){
    var x=getNumber();
    var element=x.toString();
    browser.push(element);
    var y=document.getElementById(element);
    y.click();  
    $(y).delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow');   
}

function getNumber(){   
    var randomNumber=Math.floor((Math.random() * 4)+1);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Comment: what is `simon()`?

Comment: Don't pay attention to that.It 's for the second part of my code.

Comment: Achieve what effect? Please read [ask]

Comment: Ok, thanks for advice.

Comment: Hope this works for you now.

Answer (score 0):

This will guarantee a gap of 100ms between all games

```
var tasks = []
var createTask = function(task) {
  tasks.push(function() {
      task(function() {
        tasks.shift()
        var next = tasks[0]
        next()

    })
  })
  if (tasks.length === 1) {
     tasks[0]()
  }
}

var startGame = function() {
  createTask(function(next) {
    ... // whatever happens
    // if ready call next
    setTimeout(next, 1000)
  })
}
```

http://codepen.io/lipp/pen/eZjopG

Comment: Thank you very much for help :)

Comment: You are welcome! Did the code make sense to you? Did it solve your problem?

Comment: It's very pity but no,there is still no gap between calls.I think I should work on changing the way of call .